# Line counting - How to exclude a directory and images?

Tags: linux, bash

In order to count the lines of my repository, I typed the code below, and found out that images and pdfs are also included in the word count.

```
git ls-files | xargs wc -l
```

When someone asks you for the scale of the repository, would you include the images/pdfs?
If not, could someone help me answer the questions below?

1. How to exclude the files under "/pdfs" directory
2. How to exclude .jpg and .png?

Comment: use `git ls-files --exclude-per-directory=<path of pdf dir>`

Comment: or use `--exclude=<pattern>`

Comment: this won't work if the paths contain newlines. See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc). It counts blank lines, comment lines, and physical lines of source code in many programming languages. [Cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) can take file, directory, and/or archive names as inputs. For instance, if you want to count the number of lines of code in your repository and exclude some directories while counting, you can specify those directories separated by comma like this:

```sh
cloc --exclude-dir=imagedir,pdfdir your_repository
```

[cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) will show you the report like this:

```sh
     387 text files.
     387 unique files.
      22 files ignored.

github.com/AlDanial/cloc v 1.88  T=0.97 s (376.5 files/s, 152866.0 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Go                             235          17216          11769          95308
InstallShield                    2            410              0          11178
XML                             41           1418            159           2738
Python                           5            516            523           1792
Bourne Shell                    21            266            283           1512
JSON                            19             24              0           1005
Markdown                        23            452              0            797
AsciiDoc                         4            119              0            312
Ruby                             4             44             31            238
YAML                             4              4              2            113
WiX source                       1             19             24            112
make                             3             16             25             68
DOS Batch                        2             13              2             38
WiX include                      1              0              0             28
Dockerfile                       1             13              9             17
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                           366          20530          12827         115256
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can also use CLOC with Git like this:

```sh
cloc $(git ls-files)
```

which is equivalent to

```sh
git ls-files | xargs cloc
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! You are my savior! 
I decided to use `cloc --vcs=git` in order to count files that are under git control.

Answer (score 0):

`cloc` sounds like it does the job. You should remove space+tab from IFS if you use command sub though: `IFS=$'\n' cloc $(git ls-files)`

If you just want to know a word count or line count, you could bodge it together like this. It gives you the language too. Clone the repo, test for text file / file type, count lines, delete files.

```
#!/bin/sh -e

# Get dir name from URL + remove trailing slashes - works for _most_ urls
url=${1:? No URL given}
url=${url%/}; url=${url%/}
repo=${1##*/}
repo=${repo%.git}
dir=./$repo

# Clone repo in tmp
cd "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}"

[ -e "$dir" ] && { echo Exists: "$dir" >&2; exit 1; }
trap 'rm -rf "$dir"' EXIT INT
git clone "$url"

# Get column 1 width, for alignment
max_path_length=$(printf '%s\n' "$dir/"* | wc -L)

# Extract and print the data
printf '\n%s\n\n' "$repo text files details:"
for file in "$dir"/*; do
        mime=$(file --brief --mime-type "$file")
        type=${mime%%/*}

        if [ "$type" = text ]; then
                lines=$(grep -c . "$file") || true
                lang=${mime##*/}
                printf "%-${max_path_length}s  %s\n" "${file#$dir}" "[$lang, $lines lines]"
                total_lines=$((total_lines + lines))
        fi
done

printf '\n%s\n\n' "${dir#./} total lines: $total_lines"
```

Example output:

```
$ git-wc 'git://git.savannah.gnu.org/sed.git'
Cloning into 'sed'...
remote: Counting objects: 6276, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1134/1134), done.
remote: Total 6276 (delta 4994), reused 6276 (delta 4994)
Receiving objects: 100% (6276/6276), 2.14 MiB | 495.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4994/4994), done.

sed text files details:

/AUTHORS              [plain, 6 lines]
/BUGS                 [plain, 101 lines]
/COPYING              [plain, 553 lines]
/ChangeLog-2014       [plain, 2586 lines]
/Makefile.am          [x-makefile, 123 lines]
/NEWS                 [plain, 498 lines]
/README               [plain, 12 lines]
/README-hacking       [plain, 58 lines]
/THANKS.in            [plain, 63 lines]
/basicdefs.h          [x-c, 83 lines]
/bootstrap            [x-shellscript, 930 lines]
/bootstrap.conf       [plain, 121 lines]
/cfg.mk               [plain, 343 lines]
/configure.ac         [x-m4, 294 lines]
/init.cfg             [plain, 163 lines]
/thanks-gen           [x-perl, 12 lines]

sed total lines: 5946
```

If the repo is local, you can just adjust the input methods. I'm sure the idea is clear. I know cloning the whole repo may be the dumbest way to do something like this, but sometimes you just want to know a thing. Plus you can use `bash`/`sh` - eg. `[[ "$file" == "$dir/<exclude-dir>/* ]]`.